# $rollbackViewValue() - setting initial state of form - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a simple program, where if a person types a word **'alpha'**, the form gets all its elements states **ng-prestine/ng-touched/ng-valid/ng-invalid** all to their initial states. I think I am doing it correctly but getting an error in console.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="person">{{person}}
    <button ng-click="click()">Click</button>
</form>
<script>
//Module Declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.click = function(){
        if ($scope.person = "alpha"){
            form1.$rollbackViewValue();
        }
    }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error** 
[image]

**Reference**

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `form1` isn't a defined variable in your controller. You have to use `$scope.form1.$...`

But be aware that `$rollbackViewValue` might not do what you expect. It would be easier to set the state you want your form to be in manually.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could you could be more clear about "be aware that `$rollbackViewValue` might not do what you expect", thanks!